# Kerbal Space Program: Getting the SRB-KD25k "Kickback" to orbit?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In KSP, I have a contract to test the Kickback SRB in orbit.  That seems impossible to me, how do I get a huge SRB like that into orbit?  Remember, I can't light it up until it's in orbit or the contract isn't fulfilled.  Also, I only have up to the third tier (or fourth if you count the "start") of technology researched plus Heavy Rocketry in the fourth tier.

Comment: Perhaps if you post a picture of your unlocked tech tree and how much money you have left, someone could "apollo13" this.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you need to wait until the prereqs to activate the engine -- you can use it, and then right-click on it mid-flight and select "Run Test" when the requirements are met. It's been a while, but I remember doing this at some point.

Comment: I've been using full kickbacks in orbit as ejection stages for probes. The launcher has a lot more kickbacks on it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The trick to make this easier is to lower the amount of solid fuel in the booster when you build your ship.

The [**S1 SRB-KD25k "Kickback" Solid Fuel Booster**](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/S1_SRB-KD25k_%22Kickback%22_Solid_Fuel_Booster) has a dry mass of **4.5 tonnes** and is capable of carrying **2500 units** of **solid fuel**.

[**Solid fuel**](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Solid_fuel) has a density of **0.0075 tonnes** per unit, therefore a fully loaded booster carries an additional **18.75 tonnes** (`2500 * 0.0075`) for a total mass of **23.25 tonnes**.

In the VAB, right-clicking the booster opens a menu that allows you to select the amount of fuel it contains. This value can be lowered from **2500** to **250**.

Doing so brings the total mass of the booster to **6.375 tonnes** (`4.5 + 250 * 0.0075`). That's a little under 30% of its original mass.

Comment: <slaps forehead>  Why didn't I think of that?!  Thanks!